# Add transition while switching scenes in BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine, scene

I'm working on a simple quiz type game as we speak...  Now in my game, if you click on the correct option, it adds to your score and takes you to the next level (i.e next scene).

Problem is, the switch is too abrupt... I'd like to put in a fade in effect or some kind of transition which activates when the correct option is clicked and shows the next scene...

Now there were 2 tutorials on youtube on how to do this but both of them are in German... and that's a language I have no idea about....

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of having say 100 scenes for a hundred different questions, why not use a little bit of python and change the values of text objects for each question? You could then switch to a scene which plays your fade effect before switching back where you will then have the new question. This will then speed up your game as well as keep the file size small instead of filling it with thousands of objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

A) show a transition animation before leaving the current scene

B) show a transition animation when entering the new scene

C) both A) and B)

D) switch from the current scene to an intermediate scene (showing transition) to the new scene.